# sysread returns undef, errno is EINVAL, but working?

Tags: perl, file-io

I have some code set up for non-blocking input from a system event file.

```
sysopen(FILE, $targetInput, O_NONBLOCK|O_RDONLY) or die "Failed to open $targetInput, quitting.\n";
binmode(FILE);


#More assignments and preparations here...

while (1) {

    #Code that justifies non-blocking I/O here...

    $rBytes = sysread(FILE, $buffer, 16);

    printf("%d vs %d\n", $!, EAGAIN);       
    print defined($rBytes) ? "Defined!\n" : "Undef!\n";


    if (!defined($rBytes) && $! == EAGAIN) {
        #Nothing actually read in non-blocking mode:
        usleep(1000);
    } else {
        #Got an event, moving on:
        print "Got it!\n";
        print "$rBytes!\n";
        last;
    }

}

#Logic using $buffer here...
```

This is a pretty standard setup, dozens of examples are available for this very thing. However, I have discovered that, 100% of the time, `$rBytes` remains undefined, and `$!` is set to code 22, EINVAL (Invalid Argument). Much testing has gone into ensuring that it is the `sysread` function specifically that causes this, and definitely nothing before it.

The catch is, *it works*. As you can see, my code assumes anything that is *not* a combination of `$rBytes` being undefined (always true) *and* `$!` being `EAGAIN` (always false) just sort of assumes everything is fine, since I haven't added any error handling. What follows this code block is a massive switch/case; the nonexistent data "harmlessly" passes over it all, looping back over to do it again as fast as it can.

When valid input *is* received, `$rBytes` is **still undefined**. But since `$!` is still not `EAGAIN`, it too passes to the rest of the program and functions precisely as intended, with `$buffer` containing exactly what it should. I actually would not have noticed this issue at all if I didn't glance at my CPU usage meter, and probably wouldn't try to fix it if it were a quick one-shot script.

I can safely say that an accusation of "invalid argument" is bogus. The question is, why does it give that error code, and why is `$rBytes` *always* undefined?

Comment: You check `$!` after calling `print`, not after calling `sysread`...

Comment: @ikegami There, fixed. Any other nitpicks that I've obviously already tried?

Comment: It wasn't a nitpick. `print` regularly sets `$!` on success. (`$!` is meaningless on success.)  If you want a nit, then I'll point out that you only fixed one of the uses of `$!`.

Comment: So you're saying that `sysread` also returns `$!` == `22`? If so, the next step is to provide an `strace` of the execution.

Comment: Re "What follows this code block is a massive switch/case", Actually, the next step is to give code that actually demonstrates the problem. Showing us some code when actually running other code is not too useful. In the code you posted, you are actually using the strings `O_NONBLOCK` and `O_RDONLY` rather than the constants you should have been using. In your actual code? No idea.

Comment: I... what? No, this is the actual code. As stated, what *follows this* excerpt is a switch/case that attempts to utilize the contents of `$buffer`, and never matches if there's nothing read. At this point, nearly every other line is temporary debug output, so I'm pretty certain I know where the issues are. I'm examining the `strace` results now, though it looks about as I'd expect.

Comment: Re "No, this is the actual code.", 1) You say it isn't in your question. 2) Your program wouldn't go beyond the first line because you didn't provide a file name to `sysopen` if this was really your program. 3) If this is really your program, then why didn't you address the bug I said existed in your program if that was your actual program (passing `"\x4f\x5f\x5e\x4f\x4f\x4e\x4c\x5f\x43\x4b"` instead of `2048` as `sysread`'s 3rd arg).

Comment: Rather than post 574 lines of code that mostly have no issue, I've given what is necessary. If you can not infer - based on the *given* information that `sysread` *is* able to read information properly when it exists - that a file name has indeed been assigned, I'm not sure how much help you can be. Please read the question more carefully, as all your nitpicking has already been addressed in full. Please also see: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch07_21.htm

Comment: Re "Rather than post 574 lines of code that mostly have no issue, I've given what is necessary." You should not give 574 lines of code, and you did not give what's necessary. Please provide code that you know exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I was cobbling together a quick script to mock the assumptions made thus far, I actually stumbled upon the answer myself; sure enough, all the necessary information was there in the question all along.

A typical system event file works with messages that are 24 bytes in length. This block of code was, of course, trying to extract the 16-bit timestamp from those events, and leave the rest unconsumed for later. For reasons I don't understand myself, `sysread` doesn't like that.

By ensuring that the desired length is greater than or equal to 24, `sysread` will report bytes read and `$!` as documented. 24 could be a magic number, or it could simply have problems reading a partial message from a non-blocking resource (no errors occur in blocking mode). It was still putting the appropriate data into `$buffer`, presumably because the underlying code passes it by reference and does not zero it out in the event of an error, and that is why everything after the shown block worked fine.

Comment: "A typical system event file works with messages that are 24 bytes in length." -- That sounds like necessary information that wasn't in the question all along. Showing the value of `$targetInput` might have helped. (I'm not even sure what a "system event file" is, and a quick Google search was not illuminating.)

Comment: I too would like to know waht you mean by "A typical system event file works with messages that are 24 bytes in length."